# Windows 10 SDK 10.01.14393 installation problems

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

I fresh install windows 10 home edition and then start to install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

I only select universal windows platform development, .net desktop development and asp.net web development but "setup completed with warnings".

I want to share the log file above.

Do you have any ideas for this issue ?

I also asked this question to Microsoft Community but no one answered.

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26206.0)

Incomplete components
    Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26206.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26206.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26206.0)
    Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26127.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79501' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2146889721
    Impacted workloads
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26206.0)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26206.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26206.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (2.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26206.0)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.0.26127.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\emrek\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170307010944_177_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79501\WinSdkInstall.ps1""" -SetupExe sdksetup.exe -SetupLogFolder standalonesdk -PackageId Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795 -LogFile """C:\Users\emrek\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170307010944_177_Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.log""" -SetupParameters """/features OptionId.AvrfExternal OptionId.WindowsSoftwareDevelopmentKit OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.NetFxSoftwareDevelopmentKit /quiet /norestart"""; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: -2146889721
        Return code details: The hash value is not correct.
```

Comment: today Microsoft releases the RTM of VS2017. maybe they now remove RC files and replace them with RTM files, so you may get hash issues. try to install the RTM later today

Comment: Also there is a support page for VS2017 https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/

Comment: thanks for reply. I followed link above. win10sdk installation always failed until I read an answer that about installing sdk via vpn connection.  win10sdk installed successfully.  but visual studio installation doesn't keep going on. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/#!articles/968-6918-the-package-win10sdk_1001439333version100143933300-failed-to-install .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by vpn connection. 
If you have any problem installing visual studio 2017 or windows 10 sdk try to connect vpn and continue process. 
I do not know why this kind of situation we have but you can fix this issue connecting to the net via vpn.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the corrupted files caused that error. I manually **deleted** *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.19041,version=10.0.19041.1* (or your version of windowsSDK)
folder and then in Visual Studio 2022 installer picked up modify option and **install after download** (or so) from dropdown next to **modify** button .

It won't work without delete.

**Also** For sure temporarily turn off Defender . Then if its all settled turn it on again.There are possible troubls with folder acceses. Seems.